# Children's book about a cat named Clara and a cat named Mrs. Cat

Tags: identification-request

My niece read this book in a doctor's office and it ended up being very special to her so I'd like to track it down. It's about a black cat named Clara and a adult orange cat named Mrs. Cat. Clara helps get food for some farm animals. I've tried searching the words and images and can't find anything online.

[image: Picture of hands holding book featuring illustration of orange cat and black cat]

Comment: Huh. That is a puzzler. https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/48472870-molly-finds-her-purr has a cat named Clara, but they look to be a side character.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Please take a look at the [tag wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) for identification requests and [edit your question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/posts/26390/edit) to include additional information based on the suggestions there. For example, how long ago did your niece come across this book? Where was the doctor's office—a US state? the UK? Australia? Such details help narrow down the book. Thanks!

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 8):

It appears to be the "Clara Cat Stands Guard" story from "I Love You, My Little One!" by Carol Ottolenghi.

I found it by searching with part of the text from the picture on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/iloveyoumylittle0000otto/).